# Overlapping error while generating Excel sheet

Tags: excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

**Code**

```
df.to_excel(
    writer,
    index=False,
    startrow=2,
    sheet_name=self.sheet_name
    )
ws = writer.book.get_worksheet_by_name(self.sheet_name)
ws.freeze_panes(3, 0)
workbook = writer.book
merge_head_size = workbook.add_format(
    {"bold": 1, "border": 1, "align": "left", "valign": "vcenter", 'font_size': 20 if len(df.columns.tolist())>4 else 14}) 
merge_sub_head_size = workbook.add_format(
    {"bold": 1, "border": 1, "align": "left", "valign": "vcenter", 'font_size': 10})                                

merged_data_one_range = f"B1:E1" if df.columns.tolist() else "B1:G1"
merged_data_range = f"B2:{alphabet_list[len(df.columns.tolist())-1]}2" if df.columns.tolist() else "B2:G2"
# merge_date = f"{alphabet_list[len(df.columns.tolist())-1]}" if df.columns.tolist() else "E1"

blue_background_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#00b0f0'})
conditional_format_range = f"A3:{alphabet_list[(len(df.columns.tolist())-1)]}3" if df.columns.to_list() else "A3:I3"
ws.conditional_format(conditional_format_range, {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': blue_background_format})

ws.merge_range(merged_data_one_range, self.header_name, merge_head_size)
if merged_data_one_range == 'B1:B1':
    ws.write('B1',self.header_name, workbook.add_format({"bold": 1, "border": 1, "align": "left", "valign": "vcenter", 'font_size': 20 if len(df.columns.tolist())>4 else 14}))        
            
ws.merge_range(merged_data_range, self.sub_headings, merge_sub_head_size)
```

**Error**

```
xlsxwriter.exceptions.OverlappingRange: Merge range 'B1:E1' overlaps previous merge range 'B1:E1'.
```

Any idea on how to resolve the issue?

I tried by changing the sheet variables, but it didn't worked out.

Comment: The basic issue is that the program is creating 2 overlapping merged ranges but Excel doesn't allow that so the library is raising an error. If you print out the `merged_data_one_range` and `merged_data_range` ranges you will probably find that the ranges are the same or overlapping. You just need to go through the logic of the program to figure why the ranges are overlapping and avoid doing that.

Comment: Based on the code, an overlap should not happen as 'merged_data_one_range' will only be a range across row 1, 'B1' to either 'E1' or 'G1' ` and 'merged_data_range' only selects a range in row 2 (the 2 being hard coded for any start/end coord), so could **not** result in the range 'B1:E1'. Ergo the ranges in the provided code could not overlap. There is nothing in the code that shows where the issue could lie so maybe you have a bug or this is not quite the same code that's causing the error. If no typo errors are in the code check, you have the latest versions for all used modules

Comment: [continued] And as @jmcnamara states ultimately you can also print out all merged cell ranges 'merged_data_one_range' and 'merged_data_range',  any range variable in your code that comes after `ws.merge_range(` to be doubly sure there is no attempted merging of 'B1:E1' more than once, or any other overlapping cells.